# How to format a USB or external drive in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, usb, kubuntu, external-hdd, format

I am using Kubuntu 13.04. How to format a USB or external drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use gparted, like in this [how-to](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17001/how-to-format-a-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-using-gparted/). But don't use FAT32, or you will have a 4 GByte file size limit. Use NTFS instead.

Comment: and if I want to use only with the help of Konsole, then what will be the command for formatting the USB ?

Comment: I've used `sudo cfdisk <device>` and also `sudo fdisk <device>` with success pretty often. `sudo parted` (notice: without the 'g') is a bit more user-friendly than both fdisk and cfdisk.